# Does "as to me" mean "as for me"? Does this phrase exist?

Tags: phrase-meaning

Can we use "as to me" to mean the same thing as "as for me" when we want to say: "Regarding me?"
For example: As for me, I am a teacher of Italian. Can we say: As to me, I am an Italian teacher.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*As for NOUN PHRASE* is the English marked topic construction.  You can use it to explicitly mark the topic at the beginning of a sentence, like in your example:

> **As for me**, I am a teacher of Italian.

You wouldn't always want to use this phrase, but it makes sense in the right context, for example to show a contrast between two topics:

> **He** teaches English.  **As for me**, I'm a teacher of Italian.

Here we have an unmarked topic and a marked topic contrasting with each other, so *as for* is appropriate in this context.  By explicitly marking the topic with *as for*, you draw attention to the contrast.

However, if you change the words in this phrase, you no longer have a marked topic construction.  The words *as to me* are grammatical but have no special grammatical significance or meaning.  They would work as part of a comparative construction:

> Linda speaks *as much* **to herself** *as* **to me**.

In this example, we're comparing how much Linda speaks to two different people: herself and me. In this sort of example it would be grammatical and make sense, but it isn't anything like *as for me* and isn't something people say particularly often.

So it can be grammatical, but your example doesn't work:

> ***As to me**, I am a teacher of Italian.

*As to NOUN PHRASE* can't be used in the intended meaning, so I've marked the example with a * to show that it is unacceptable.

Comment: "As to..." is a way of introducing a subject, particularly as one item of a list that has already begun. For example: "I am worried about my trip to Brittany next week because of travel arrangements and the weather. The travel arrangements are uncertain because ... As to the weather, ..." . In that usage "As to" could be replaced by "Regarding,..." or "As regards,..." but @duckplane is right that for some reason not clear to me it does not work with "me". It would work however with "As to my profession,..."

Comment: Hmm, nope, those examples still don't work as marked topic constructions.  Note that the complements of *as for* are topics, not subjects, and although they tend to be coreferential *with* the subject, they do not grammatically function as subjects themselves.

Comment: Just to clarify when  used the word "subject" I was using it in its ordinary sense not in its sense as a technical term in grammar.